# increase size of text on mouse hover css/jquery/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a large paragraph. Within that there is a span tag with id for a particular word. On mouse hover the size of that particular word in para should increase. It can come above the other text and cover the contents in paragraph but it should not affect the alignment of other text.

Comment: well i dint try much.... i was thinking to use hover to increase size but that could affect the size. So i posted it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't object to a pure CSS solution, with its somewhat imperfect cross-browser compatibility you can use `:hover:after` and `content: attr(title);` to achieve this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(
      function() {

      }
      );

  </script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }

  p span.special {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    color: #f90;
  }
  p span.special:hover:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
    padding: 0.2em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Est diam cras diam ultrices sagittis. Purus platea in nascetur nunc ac. In lacus massa. Sit pulvinar egestas amet magnis, nec! Ac pulvinar ac magna? Odio hac <span class="special" title="facilisis">facilisis</span>, in massa. Nascetur lacus lacus aliquet! Quis? Augue? Ultrices sit porttitor pulvinar a rhoncus, etiam, mauris phasellus lorem augue ac. Facilisis pulvinar integer urna, egestas magna, odio, nisi, vut odio magna integer.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Demo at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ajobo3/).

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
var clone;
$("span").hover(function() {
    clone = $(this).clone()
    $(this).after(clone);
    $(this).css( {
        'font-size' : '2em',
        'background-color' : '#fff',
        'position' : 'absolute'
    })
}, function() {
    clone.remove();
    $(this).css( {
        'font-size' : '1em',
        'position' : 'inherit'
    })
});
```

Check the running example at http://jsfiddle.net/39YKG/

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the mouseover for that word is fired create a new element in the DOM (without effecting the current word element) and have it absolutely position on the page exactly where the word element is (thanks to jQuery's `.position()`).

With some padding you can make it align perfectly to the word.

Don't forget to remove it on mouseout.

Comment: I should go for creating a ghost-element that shows and hide on hovering instead of creating a new one, every time a hover occurs. But that is some fine-tuning I guess.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('span#yourId').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css('font-size', '30px');
});
```

Assuming 30px is the max size you want.